# what does ".=" means in AT&T assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system

I am trying to code a boot program.The contents like following:

```
.text
balabala
.globl _start
_start:
balabala

.=_start+510
.byte 0x55,0xaa
```

And by the way,I also cannt understand ".byte 0x55,0xaa" means?
what is its function and how does it work?
The more details,the better.

Comment: `.` is the current location. `=` assigns a value to a symbol, so `. = _start + 510` sets the current location to `_start + 510`.

Comment: `.byte 0x55,0xaa` will define two bytes `0x55` and `0xAA`. It has no particular function, except when those two values are found in boot sector at offset +510 and +511, the BIOS will think the boot sector contains valid boot-up code, and it will execute it (if the disk will be overwritten/formatted by some random data, it's very likely that "magic marker" will be not there in the boot sector, making the BIOS avoiding execution of the wrong content).

Comment: Brief answer and solved my problem!Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembler converts data and instructions into bytes. Unlike a compiler, there is generally a 1:1 matching between assembly instructions and memory. The . symbol has traditionally been used to indicate the current offset from the start of the current program section.

It is most commonly used to determine the size of objects.

Using your example modified:

```
SOMEDATA:
    .byte 0x55,0xaa
```

This allocates 2 bytes with the value 55 and AA and assigns the internal label SOMEDATA to the location with that data.

If I added immediately afterwards

```
SOMEDATA:
    .byte 0x55,0xaa
SOMEDATALENGTH = . - SOMEDATA
```

that would define a symbol giving the number of bytes allocated (2 in this case). Some assemblers have complex macro capabilities that can describe elaborate data structures. Using . is very common in setting up such structures.

Some assemblers allow assignment to the . symbol as above.

```
_start:
.=_start+510
 .byte 0x55,0xaa
```

This causes the allocator to be incremented by 510 bytes. It then creates a 510 byte gap between the location _start and the 2 bytes given the value 55 and AA. Usually the gap is filled with zeros but that depends upon the assembler.

Comment: Thank you for your patience!You have given many useful details!